# Please don't include edits in close vote limit calculation

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I performed an edit on a post in the close queue. After the edit, I got the dreaded:

[image]

I was not aware that an edit counted as a close vote. I guess this is the first time its happened to me on an edit.

I sometimes (often?) edit a question and then select ***Skip***. I do it to improve the question even though I don't have the subject matter expertise to vote on it.

Please don't count an edit as a close vote.

Comment: If you use the actual Edit button in the review queue, it has an implicit and binding Leave Open vote attached to it which [immediately completes review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5833111).

Answer (score 3):

Skip is the only action that is not counted as a review.  If you don't want your edit to count as a review, go to the actual post, and edit it there.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.... are we supposed to accept answers on feature requests? Or do we wait for Meta to move? (And thanks for the suggestion).

Comment: You don't have to accept if you don't want to.  I would interpret an accept as [status-completed].